# PHP Session persistance issue

Tags: php, session, persist

I ran into a very annoying problem two days ago, regarding PHP sessions, as it seems they don't persist through pages, and the session_start(); function starts a new session rather than resuming the existing one. This even happens on reloads.

Here's how the session section in my php.ini looks like.

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx 

session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   no value    no value
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   1   1
```

I'm running an Ubuntu server, and the www-data user has got writing and reading permisions on the /tmp folder. The session files exist, but it chooses to start a new one for some reason.

OS : Ubuntu 12.04 
PHP Version : 5.3.1
Web server : Apache 2.2

Thank's in advance for any suggestion or piece of advice, and, of course, for your time !

[PROBLEM SOLVED]

Problem solved, I had to set the cookie domain to "example.com" (replace with your own domain) and make sure I make my redirections to "exemple.com/bla/bla" rather than "www.exemple.com/bla/bla".

Comment: do yo uhave cookies enabled on your browser?

Comment: yes, cookies are enabled on the browser.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please select a correct answer below. If you solved your own problem, answer your question below and then select that as an answer. Solutions to issues do not belong in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify you cookie exists by examining http headers maybe in chrome? Are you sure the problem is not just with you?

Also verify the domain name is set properly for the cookie. Are you doing funky things with domain names etc?

Comment: I think this is a comment more than answer :)

Comment: The cookies do exist, and I didn't specify any domain name for the cookie. Should I use 'example.com' or 'www.example.com' ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that www is considered a subdomain, and hence session does not persist when created from a non www url. To fix this, I usually use .htaccess to ensure that all non www urls eg. `http://domain.com/file.php` is redirected to `http://www.domain.com/file.php`